# How to detect when a specific shortcut is pressed for vscode extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am making my first vscode extension and i want to maybe `console.log` something when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. How would i do that through javascript?

Comment: https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/debugging-extensions/

Comment: You need to implement a command and set its default keybinding to Ctrl+B.  I don't believe you can just listen to keyboard events that are not bound to one of your commands.  This, of course, means you are co-opting Ctrl+B and whatever it usually does won't be triggered.

Comment: Oh i see, but how exactly do i set bindings for commands in javascript? Could you please give an example?

Comment: read the part for keybindings in the VSC doc